# Page numbering by group on report

Tags: ms-access

I have a report where I want to show records by group in different pages. 
Assume that groups have enough records to cover more than one page . In addition in the group footer section I have totals.
I want page numbering by group . For example group 1 covers 2 pages so the numbering must be Page 1 and Page 2 , group 2 covers 3 pages so the Page number must be Page 1 ,Page 2 and Page 3. 
I have succeeded on numbering by group but when the page shows only the group footer section where I keep the totals the page numbering resets for example if Page 3 of Group 2(previous example) shows only the totals instead of Page 3 shows Page 1. The code I use is :

```
Private sub GroupHeader 
Page =1
End sub

Private sub GroupFooter
Page = 0
End sub
```

Comment: I forgot to mention when I have the page numbering on footer the numbering is OK. But I don't know how to copy the text value from the text box on footer to the header